# Can you protect/obfuscate the URL for assets on Cloud Files?

Tags: cdn

Just opened an account with Rackspace Cloud Files and I'm looking to protect our video assets. By protect I want to make sure that the user is logged in with an active account prior to serving up the video stream. I suppose it could be done in the .htaccess, however if I use LiveHeaders or any other sniffer I will see the CDN's URL. We will be serving this video to the iPhone as well as through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download it on server side and send it to client. Dont ?
Why you have to provide CDC URL ?

For example, using CURL...

Comment: Well the point of running it through the CDN is to use their bandwidth. Seems like Amazon S3 might be a better option for what I'm trying to do.